# Pathfinder Office - how to tell if an external antenna was used with GPS

Tags: gps, pathfinder

Does pathfinder office store the antenna name in any of the log files?  I'm trying to go back and compare old files to determine if data collected with an external antenna did any better than those using only the internal antenna.

Comment: no, though you can use the Pseudorange to differentiate types of antenna http://trl.trimble.com/docushare/dsweb/Get/Document-3823/24177-03-ENG%20(MapSys_Jan2002_GenRef).pdf